# Split a string on new lines, but include empty lines

Tags: lua

Let's say I have a string with the contents

```
local my_str = [[
line1
line2

line4
]]
```

I'd like to get the following table:

```
{"line1","line2","","line4"}
```

In other words, I'd like the blank line 3 to be included in my result. I've tried the following:

```
  local result = {};
  for line in string.gmatch(my_str, "[^\n]+") do
      table.insert(result, line);
  end
```

However, this produces a result which will not include the blank line 3.

How can I make sure the blank line is included? Am I just using the wrong regex?

Comment: try `string.gmatch(my_str, "(.-)%c") `

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326368/iterate-over-lines-including-blank-lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
  local result = {};
  for line in string.gmatch(my_str .. "\n", "(.-)\n") do
      table.insert(result, line);
  end
```

If you don't want the empty fifth element that gives you, then get rid of the blank line at the end of `my_str`, like this:

```
local my_str = [[
line1
line2

line4]]
```

(Note that a newline at the beginning of a long literal is ignored, but a newline at the end is not.)

Comment: Thanks! Out of curisoity, I changed `my_str .. "\n"` to just `my_str` and that seemed to get rid of my extra newline at the end issue and give me the output I wanted. Why did you add the extra new line there?

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum Because if there's no newline at all on the end, then you'd lose the whole last line.

Comment: ah, ok. That makes sense. In my usecase the string `my_str` is always guaranteed to have a newline as the last character. So that's probably why it works for me. Good to know about this little bit of safety though!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `+` with `*`, but that won't work in all Lua versions; LuaJIT will add random empty strings to your result (which isn't even technically wrong).

If your string always includes a newline character at the end of the last line like in your example, you can just do something like `"([^\n]*)\n"` to prevent random empty strings and the last empty string.

In Lua 5.2+ you can also just use a frontier pattern to check for either a newline or the end of the string: `[^\n]*%f[\n\0]`, but that won't work in LuaJIT either.

If you need to support LuaJIT **and** don't have the trailing newline in your actual string, then you could just add it manually:

```lua
string.gmatch(my_str .. "\n", "([^\n]*)\n")
```